# Why are apostrophes used when omitting letters in words like "'em" or "ridin'"?

Tags: apostrophe

The apostrophe in English is a very valuable sign. I want to know about the way it is used to omit letters of a word. I often see authors omitting letters in dialogues (in books, articles, blogs, scripts):

- They had to take 'em away. ('em=them)
- I was down 'n' broken last night. ('n'=and)
- We were ridin' to town yesterday. (ridin'=riding)

Why is it done so and how bad is it in dialogues (especially in books)?

Comment: It's pretty bad. The general advice for learners should be to *avoid* such contractions. None of the examples are "natural", and they don't save any time in the written form anyway. There're nothing at all unusual about ***It's*** and ***don't*** in my preceding sentences, but it would just look stupid if I'd written ***precedin'*** in this one. The only real justification for ***'em, 'n', ridin',*** etc. is in "reported speech", where the writer wishes to explicitly convey that his subject speaker has a regional accent, is uneducated, or similar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but that's exactly what I often see in books.

Comment: No you don't. Your first two examples also include "errors" that no native speaker would be likely to make, so it's unlikely you've *ever* read exactly those words, let alone *often*. And the last one is extremely unlikely in any context - it might just about occur in reported speech, but it's not easy to imagine *why* anyone would want to do it (if you wanted to indicate "substandard speech" there, *We **wuz** riding to town* would probably be more likely).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those aren't book sentences. But I remember reading Harry Harrison and Ray Bradbury and they had such stuff there!

Comment: I remember reading Harry Harrison and Ray Bradbury too, but I doubt you'll actually find a single instance of ***[verb]in'*** in the collected works of either, *except* where it's reported speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mostly in speech parts, yes. I have to add that to the question!

Comment: What do you mean by "Direct speech"? Do you mean **[dialogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue)**?

Comment: @Catija Ah, yes.. I'm gonna re-reedit this one once more!

Comment: @SovereignSun: Whereas most native speakers would enunciate the "double consonant" in something like ***bookkeeping***, I think very few would actually do this with, say, ***shooting gallery***. So strictly speaking including an apostrophe in the latter *(**shootin' gallery**)* would be a "more accurate" reflection of how almost *everyone* speaks. But in practice we only write it like that in specific contexts where we want to call attention to the fact that *the specific speaker* has a dialectal / conversational / uneducated way of speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authors in literary works like to add flavor to their characters. One of the way they do this is by giving the characters accents. An easy (if not only) way to show this accent is by changing the spelling of the words in the character's dialogue sections.

So, omitting letters (or misspelling the words), is a way of showing that someone speaks with an accent and allows readers to read the text in their head (or out loud) with the similar accent.

This is commonly done in both books and scripts.

You'll *usually* find that, while the dialogue may have these elisions or misspellings, the rest of the text will have standard English spellings.

Answer (score 1):

In real life, speakers often smooth or cut off the ends and beginnings of words.  This happens a lot with common pronouns and auxiliary verbs.

An author trying to recreate in text form the way people speak in real life will use these to indicate that the omission of letters was not a mistake.